# Deploying the adapter shows null in console

Tags: adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I am not touch with worklight for past 3 months. but lots of changes made in version. In one of my project i created http adapter its working fine before. But now i try to run that project it shows some error. I cant get help in ibm forum because they changed my account to read only.

```
[2013-02-15 10:20:37] Starting adapter deployment on Worklight Server
[2013-02-15 10:20:37] Deploying adapter: university
[2013-02-15 10:20:37] Server host: localhost
[2013-02-15 10:20:37] Server port: 8085
[2013-02-15 10:20:37] null
[2013-02-15 10:20:37] Adapter deployment failed
[2013-02-15 10:20:37] ERROR
```

it was running in version platformVersion="5.0.2". Whether i need to change the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to review the changes made in the authentication mechanism starting Worklight 5.0.0.3; make the appropriate changes in your project and re-deploy.

IBM tech note: [IBM Worklight Project Auto-upgrade to 5.0.0.3 Authentication Model](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036063)

Note that you did not supply any other information about your project and environment setup.

Comment: Hi idan im using Developer version and developed one small mock app before in 5.0.2 now version changes. Whether WL didnt give support for developer version ?. Few months before its working fine due to update i got this issue. I feel it wont be authentication issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this

```
<loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="0"/>
```

instead Change maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode from 0 to  2. Enable the adapter deployement.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the change to maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode did not resolve the problem. I found that the user name and password in my adapter's data source definition are mandatory (even if the database does not have a user name and password set).

Comment: Hi stephen post ur question in separate thread with Error log. so it easy to find fault in ur code.